# Incorrect assignment of spark.executor.instances

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am using m4.2x master + 12 r5.12x core instances to run my spark job (spark 2.4, EMR 5.21)

I gave the following cluster config:

```
[
 {
   "classification": "spark-defaults",
   "properties": {
     "spark.executor.memory": "39219M",
     "spark.driver.memory": "39219M",
     "spark.driver.cores": "5",
     "spark.executor.cores": "5",
     "spark.memory.storageFraction": "0.27",
     "spark.memory.fraction": "0.80",
     "spark.executor.instances": "107",
     "spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead": "4357M",
     "spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled": "false",
     "spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead": "4357M"
   },
   "configurations": []
 }
]
```

As [ec2 instance types](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) says r5.12x has memory of 384 GB. And I calculated the above as follows

```
# of cores per executor = 5
# of executors per r5.12x instance = floor(48/5) = 9
spark.executor.instances = 9 * 12 - 1 (minus 1 for driver)
spark.executor.memory = floor(((383 * 1024)/9) * 0.9) = 39219MB
spark.executor.memoryOverhead = floor(((383 * 1024)/9) * 0.1) =  4357MB
(and same for driver)
```

Yet when the cluster launches, 95 executors + 1 driver is created (instead of 107 executors + 1 driver). Each with storage memory (as per spark UI) of 29 GB (which should have been spark.memory.storageFraction * 39219 ~ 30.63 GB). Why are 12 less executors created (including driver)?  And why is storage memory in UI less ? Am I correct about the formula used to derive storage memory in UI ?

Comment: Maybe you can compare with this : https://aws.amazon.com/fr/blogs/big-data/best-practices-for-successfully-managing-memory-for-apache-spark-applications-on-amazon-emr/

Comment: I am following the same.